# Web menu doesn't work in chrome

Tags: html, image, menu

My site is at http://www.eluonpidu.com

The menu images aren't appearing in chrome the first time you visit the page.  IE and Firefox work as expected.  If I refresh the page, then the images appear for Chrome.

Comment: Looks fine to me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @phil I can see his issue in Chrome, though refreshing doesn't make the images appear for me. There is a nested table without a width attribute and it is collapsing.

Answer (score 2):

On the the code below you need to add `width="100%"`:

```
<td id="manuu">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
```

That should fix your issue.